# Mostrar nombre segun select en otro input

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla donde tengo, el id, codigo del departamento y el nombre completo de este y lo que quiero es que cuando selecione una opcion aparezca el nombre completo del departamento pero solo me esta mostrando es el id

Tengo esta funcion para realizar eso

```
 function cambioOpciones()
    {

   document.getElementById('dep').value=document.getElementById('cod').value;

    }
```

y el select lo codifique asi

```
   <select class="form-control" name="cod" id="cod" onchange="cambioOpciones();">
               <option>Seleccione el departamento</option>
              <?php foreach ($dep as $d):?>
               <option value="<?php echo $d['id'];?>"><?php echo ucwords($d['cod_dep']);?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
          </select>
```

Comment: ¿De dónde tiene que tomar el nombre completo del departamento? En el código que has compartido ese dato no aparece en ninguna parte. ¿Acaso es esto: `$d['cod_dep']`?

Comment: Tiene que tomarlo de otra tabla donde esta el id sin embargo no se si llamar a ese nombre con un query aparte o se puede hacer en el mismo for del select

Comment: Lo mejor es hacerlo todo de una vez, no usando dos consultas aparte. Mejor traer todo lo que necesites en una sola consulta y ganas en rendimiento. Además desde HTML cuentas con los atributos `data` por si quieres guardar más información en un cualquier elemento HTML. No sé si aquí bastaría con que en el `value` de cada `option` pongas el  código y en el texto del option el nombre del departamento, algo parecido al ejemplo que te puse en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Si el nombre del departamento está en el `text` de las opciones del `select` que presentas, puedes hacer esto.

He puesto datos de prueba, dado que no tengo acceso a tu código de servidor.

He hecho algunos cambios. Por ejemplo, como *buena práctica*<sup>1</sup>  se recomienda evitar tener llamadas a funciones dentro de los elementos HTML. Por eso verás que he quitado el `onChange` del `select`. Tú puedes escuchar los cambios desde el código Javascript usando el `id`  del elemento. Además, esto te da la ventaja de usar `this`, a través del cual puedes acceder a cualquier valor o propiedad del elemento.

Aquí he supuesto que quieres mostrar los datos en un `input`, y su valor se actualiza de acuerdo al departamento seleccionado, tomando su `value` y el `text` que hay escrito en él.

```js
var cboCodigos = document.getElementById('cod');
var ibxDepartamento = document.getElementById('dep');

cboCodigos.onchange = function() {
  var cboText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  var cboValue = this.value;
  ibxDepartamento.value = cboValue + ": " + cboText;
};
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="cod" id="cod">
  <option>Seleccione el departamento</option>
  <option value="1">Departamento 1</option>
  <option value="2">Departamento 2</option>
  <option value="3">Departamento 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<input id="dep" type="text" />
```

---

**Notas:**

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Esta práctica es recomendada para tener el código lo más independiente posible. Si tú tienes cientos de elementos HTML que usan una misma función y tienes que cambiar algo como el nombre de la función, tendrás que ir a buscar los cientos o miles de archivos donde se invoca esa función para cambiarla. En cambio, escuchando por el `id` puedes cambiar lo que quieras en el código Javascript sin que esto afecte a tus archivos HTML.</sub>